# Multiply vector elements by a scalar value using STL

Tags: c++, stl, vector, element, operation

Hi I want to (multiply,add,etc) vector by scalar value for example `myv1 * 3` , I know I can do a function with a forloop , but is there a way of doing this using STL function? Something like the {Algorithm.h :: transform  function }?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Yes, using `std::transform`:

```
std::transform(myv1.begin(), myv1.end(), myv1.begin(),
               std::bind(std::multiplies<T>(), std::placeholders::_1, 3));
```

Before C++17 you could use `std::bind1st()`, which was deprecated in C++11.

```
std::transform(myv1.begin(), myv1.end(), myv1.begin(),
               std::bind1st(std::multiplies<T>(), 3));
```

For the placeholders;

```
#include <functional>
```

Comment: Any illumination on what std::bind() is doing in the first example?

Comment: Is this expected to be faster than a loop?

Answer (score 32):

If you can use a `valarray` instead of a `vector`, it has builtin operators for doing a scalar multiplication.

```
v *= 3;
```

If you have to use a `vector`, you can indeed use `transform` to do the job:

```
transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), _1 * 3);
```

(assuming you have something similar to [Boost.Lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/lambda.html) that allows you to easily create anonymous function objects like `_1 * 3` :-P)

Comment: Valarrays are the correct solution IMO. With luck, your implementation uses SSE instructions to implement the procedure, making it significantly faster. See http://www.pixelglow.com/macstl/valarray/ for one such implementation of valarray. Unfortunately, its not very widespread, so if you want the advantages of SSE instructions you'll probably have to use compiler intrinsics...

Comment: @Dragon: `valarray` is the best STL solution, but it's not very good for high-performance computing because it tends to copy data in memory a lot, and produces sequences of small loops containing single operations which have poor memory access patterns. It is easier to upgrade from `valarray` to a proper expression template system, though.

Answer (score 28):

Modern C++ solution for your question.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<double> myarray;
double myconstant{3.3};
std::transform(myarray.begin(), myarray.end(), myarray.begin(), [&myconstant](auto& c){return c*myconstant;});
```

Comment: I'd make it simpler just an empty capture lambda, and get ride of the const object. After all, this id supposed to be a Kickstarter.

Answer (score 2):

I think `for_each` is very apt when you want to traverse a vector and manipulate each element according to some pattern, in this case a simple lambda would suffice:

```
std::for_each(myv1.begin(), mtv1.end(), [](int &el){el *= 3; });
```

note that any variable you want to capture for the lambda function to use (say that you e.g. wanted to multiply with some predetermined scalar), goes into the bracket as a reference.

Comment: This is not the purpose of `std::for_each`. `std::for_each` applies some (probably stateful) function object to a range and then returns this function object. 
If you want to transform a range use `std::transform` to make your intent more clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you had to store the results in a **new vector**, then you could use the [`std::transform()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform?) from the `<algorithm>` header:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    const double scale = 2;
    std::vector<double> vec_input{1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<double> vec_output(3); // a vector of 3 elements, Initialized to zero
    // ~~~
    std::transform(vec_input.begin(), vec_input.end(), vec_output.begin(),
                   [&scale](double element) { return element *= scale; });
    // ~~~
    return 0;
}
```

So, what we are saying here is,

- take the values (`element`s) of `vec_input` starting from the beginning (`vec_input.begin()`) to the end (`vec_input.begin()`),

  - essentially, with the first two arguments, you specify a range of elements  (`[beginning, end)`) to transform,
    range
- pass each `element` to the last argument, lambda expression,
- take the output of lambda expression and put it in the `vec_output` starting from the beginning (`vec_output.begin()`).

  - the third argument is to specify the beginning of the destination vector.

The lambda expression

- captures the value of scale factor (`[&scale]`) from outside by reference,
- takes as its input a vector element of type double (passed to it by `std::transform()`)
- in the body of the function, it returns the final result,

  - which, as I mentioned above, will be consequently stored in the `vec_input`.

---

Final note: Although unnecessary, you could pass lambda expression per below:

```cpp
[&scale](double element) -> double { return element *= scale; }
```

It explicitly states that the output of the lambda expression is a double. However, we can omit that, because the compiler, in this case, can deduce the return type by itself.

Answer (score -1):

I know this not STL as you want, but it is something you can adapt as different needs arise.

Below is a template you can use to calculate; 'func' would be the function you want to do: multiply, add, and so on; 'parm' is the second parameter to the 'func'. You can easily extend this to take different func's with more parms of varied types.

```
template<typename _ITStart, typename _ITEnd, typename _Func , typename _Value >
_ITStart xform(_ITStart its, _ITEnd ite, _Func func, _Value parm)
{
    while (its != ite) { *its = func(*its, parm); its++; }
    return its;
}
...

int mul(int a, int b) { return a*b; }

vector< int > v;

xform(v.begin(), v.end(), mul, 3); /* will multiply each element of v by 3 */
```

Also, this is not a 'safe' function, you must do type/value-checking etc. before you use it.

Comment: This works, but is essentially reinventing the wheel, as `std::transform` already does this for you.