# std::transform using C++0x lambda expression

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, transform

How is this done in C++0x?

```
std::vector<double> myv1;
std::transform(myv1.begin(), myv1.end(), myv1.begin(),
               std::bind1st(std::multiplies<double>(),3));
```

Original question and solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885095/c-multiply-vector-elements-by-a-scalar-value-using-stl).

Comment: ....was this taken from this other post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885095/c-multiply-vector-elements-by-a-scalar-value-using-stl

Comment: @ianmac45 - yes, I linked to this above

Comment: @ianmac45 - my bad, it was an edit in the interests of full disclosure

Comment: Why not just `for_each(begin(myv1), end(myv1), [](double& a) { a *= 3; }`?

Comment: @Dario - for_each does not modify the elements - I tried this as a solution to the original q - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662845/why-is-stdfor-each-a-non-modifying-sequence-operation

Comment: @Steve Townsend: As pointed out in the thread you linked, `for_each` is **of course allowed** to modify non-const elements of your sequence - non-modification refers to the container *structure* which we leave untouched.

Comment: @Dario: You should add that as an answer. I'll remove mine.

Comment: @GMan: Thanks - here you are ;)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
std::transform(myv1.begin(), myv1.end(), myv1.begin(), 
   [](double d) -> double { return d * 3; });
```

Comment: `-> double` is unnecessary; it gets automatically deduced.

Comment: @potato - it's supposed to, but current compilers sometimes ignore this fact.  Better to just put it in all the time.

Comment: An alternative way of that is: `std::transform(myv1.begin(), myv1.end(),myv1.begin(),myv1.end(), std::bind(std::multiplies<double>(),_1,3));`

Answer (score 32):

The main original motivation for using that functional style for these cases in C++ was, "aaagh! iterator loops!", and C++0x removes that motivation with the range-based for statement. I know that part of the point of the question was to find out the lambda syntax, but I think the answer to the question "How is this done in C++0x?" is:

```
for(double &a : myv1) { a *= 3; }
```

There's no actual function object there, but if it helps you could pretend that `{ a *= 3; }` is a highly abbreviated lambda. For usability it amounts to the same thing either way, although the draft standard defines range-based for in terms of an equivalent `for` loop.

Comment: Ah yah. I typically forget about that since I don't use a compiler that supports it. :( Definitely the best solution.

Comment: what's the name for this construct?  I am still not familiar with what's in C++0x.

Comment: "range-based for statement", 6.5.4 in n3090. Added to the answer.

Comment: Townsend. I think it's called 'ranged-based for-loop'. In Java this same construct is called foreach =/

Answer (score 28):

Just do as Dario says:

```
for_each(begin(myv1), end(myv1), [](double& a) { a *= 3; });
```

`for_each` is allowed to modify elements, saying it cannot is a myth.

Comment: +1 because this seems a more natural fit to me in the original question

Comment: +1 for "for_each is allowed to modify elements."  I participated in a very heated debate about this years ago.

Answer (score 8):

Using a mutable approach, we can use `for_each` to directly update the sequence elements through references.

```
for_each(begin(myv1), end(myv1), [](double& a) { a *= 3; });
```

---

There has been some debate going on if `for_each` is actually allowed to modify elements as it's called a "non-mutating" algorithm.

What that means is `for_each` isn't allowed to alter the *sequence* it operates on (which refers to changes of the sequence **structure** - i.e. invalidating iterators). This doesn't mean we cannot modify the non-const **elements** of the vector as usual - the structure itself is left untouched by these operations.

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
vector<double> myv1;
transform(myv1.begin(), myv1.end(), myv1.begin(), [](double v)
{
    return v*3.0;
});
```

Comment: To each his own, I suppose.  Tho I hasten to point out that mine *is* the correct formatting. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using VS2012 which support the C++11 bind adaptor. To bind the first element of the binary function (as bind1st use to do) you need to add an 
_1 (placeholder argument). Need to include the functional for bind.

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
std::transform( myv1.begin(), myv1.end(), myv1.begin(),
                 std::bind( std::multiplies<double>(),3,_1));
```