# Equivalent of python map function using lambda

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14

I am wondering if it is possible to write a C++ equivalent of the Python function [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), using the automatic return type deduction feature. What I have in mind is something like this:

```
vector<int> input({1,2,3});
auto output=apply(input,[](int num){return num*num;});

//output should be a vector {1,4,9}
```

I do know about `std::transform`, but in the present state of affairs, writing a range loop seems easier.

Comment: Using std::transform would be the way to go - what do you think is wrong with this solution? It is quite concise in my opinion.

Comment: A loop doesn't require much more typing, right? And a loop is more readable I feel (there are people who agree with me it seems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885317/stdtransform-using-c0x-lambda-expression).

Comment: I think it would be slightly less typing. I guess readability is personal preference - I would personally just use a loop for a simple case like this.

Comment: I also always thought that `std::transform()` is less powerful than Python's `map()` but actually it is more powerful because you can decide on any `output_iterator` that the `std::transform()` should write to. This means you can very quickly change from e.g. printing (`ostream_iterator<>(cout)`) to aggregating a set of unique values by using `insert_iterator<>(set, set.begin())` (of course with correct syntax, but you get the idea)

Comment: I agree, but sometimes, all I need is the python map()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can certainly be done and would probably look something like this:

```
template <class Container, class Function>
auto apply (const Container &cont, Function fun) {
    std::vector< typename
            std::result_of<Function(const typename Container::value_type&)>::type> ret;
    ret.reserve(cont.size());
    for (const auto &v : cont) {
        ret.push_back(fun(v));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

If you want to be super general and handle C arrays and everything, you might need to add a couple of overloads for the special cases.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f43fc063a8dbe613)

Answer (score 7):

[Baum mit Augen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33379228/2069064)'s answer is most of the way there. Just takes a few more steps to support anything that is for-each-able:

```
template <typename C, typename F>
auto apply(C&& container, F&& func)
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    using E = std::decay_t<decltype(std::forward<F>(func)(
        *begin(std::forward<C>(container))))>;

    std::vector<E> result;
    auto first = begin(std::forward<C>(container));
    auto last = end(std::forward<C>(container));

    result.reserve(std::distance(first, last));
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        result.push_back(std::forward<F>(func)(*first));
    }
    return result;
}
```

We can even go one step further and make this SFINAE-able by not using C++14 `auto` deduction and instead moving the failure up to the deduction phase. Start with a helper for `begin`/`end`:

```
namespace adl_helper {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    template <typename C>
    auto adl_begin(C&& c) -> decltype(begin(std::forward<C>(c))) {
        return begin(std::forward<C>(c));
    }

    template <typename C>
    auto adl_end(C&& c) -> decltype(end(std::forward<C>(c))) {
        return end(std::forward<C>(c));
    }    
}

using adl_helper::adl_begin;
using adl_helper::adl_end;
```

And then use that to deduce `E` earlier:

```
using adl_helper::adl_begin;
using adl_helper::adl_end;

template <typename C,
          typename F,
          typename E = std::decay_t<decltype(std::declval<F>()(
              *adl_begin(std::declval<C>())
              ))>
           >
std::vector<E> apply(C&& container, F&& func)
{
    /* mostly same as before, except using adl_begin/end instead
       of unqualified begin/end with using
    */
}
```

Now we can test at compile time if some container/function pair is `apply`-able, and the error is a deduction failure instead of a usage failre:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
auto x = apply(arr, []{ return 'A'; });

main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:45:52: error: no matching function for call to 'apply(int [3], main()::<lambda()>)'
    auto x = apply(arr, []() -> char { return 'A'; });
                                                    ^
main.cpp:29:16: note: candidate: template<class C, class F, class E> std::vector<E> apply(C&&, F&&)
 std::vector<E> apply(C&& container, F&& func)
                ^
main.cpp:29:16: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:25:50: error: no match for call to '(main()::<lambda()>) (int&)'
           typename E = decltype(std::declval<F>()(
                                                  ^
```

---

As pointed out, this would not handle a container of input iterators well. So let's fix it. We need something to determine the size of the container. If the container has a `size()` member function, we can use that. Otherwise if the iterators do not have category `input_iterator_tag` (don't know of any other way to distinguish input iterators...), we can use that. Otherwise, we're kind of out of luck. A good way of doing decreasing order of preference like this is to introduce a `chooser` hierarchy:

```
namespace details {
    template <int I> struct chooser : chooser<I-1> { };
    template <> struct chooser<0> { };
}
```

And then just walk down:

```
namespace details {
    template <typename C>
    auto size(C& container, chooser<2>) -> decltype(container.size(), void())
    {
        return container.size();
    }

    template <typename C,
              typename It = decltype(adl_begin(std::declval<C&>()))
              >
    auto size(C& container, chooser<1>) 
    -> std::enable_if_t<
        !std::is_same<std::input_iterator_tag,
            typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category
        >::value,
        size_t>
    {
        return std::distance(adl_begin(container), adl_end(container));
    }

    template <typename C>
    size_t size(C& container, chooser<0>)
    {
        return 1; // well, we have no idea
    }
}

template <typename C>
size_t size(C& container)
{
    return size(container, details::chooser<10>{});
}
```

Then we can use `size()` to `reserve()` our vector to the best of our ability:

```
template <typename C,
          typename F,
          typename E = std::decay_t<decltype(std::declval<F>()(
              *adl_begin(std::declval<C>())
              ))>
           >
std::vector<E> apply(C&& container, F&& func)
{
    std::vector<E> result;
    result.reserve(size(container));

    for (auto&& elem : container) {
        result.push_back(std::forward<F>(func)(std::forward<decltype(elem)>(elem)));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Neat, nice generalization of my answer; +1. May I ask: Why the perfect forwarding of the function argument? The standard library (which, of course, is not perfect) passes by value. Is there a notable benefit?

Comment: Btw, *"anything that is for-each-able"* is not quite true as `std::for_each` supports input iterators and `result.reserve(std::distance(first, last));` would break stuff with those. (Before you ask: I will not deliver an example where that would make sense, I am just being pedantic.)

Comment: @BaummitAugen Input iterators handled :)

Comment: How does one use this? The prior example just returns a constant. I'm thinking something like:
apply(intValues, [](elem) {
 return elem*2;
});

Comment: @UserOneFourTwo What prior example returns a constant?

Comment: auto x = apply(arr, []{ return 'A'; }); 
How would I get it to do something with an item of arr?

Comment: @UserOneFourTwo I don't understand what you're asking, sorry.

Comment: How do I use apply() as defined above, on the array [1,2,3] to return the array [3,6,9] with the function body { return item*3; } ?

Answer (score 4):

This has already been discussed in comments, but I think it should also be given as an answer:
The function [`std::transform`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/) from `<algorithm>` does what you want.

The following code works for me:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

//...

vector<int> input({1,2,3});
transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), [](int num){return num*num;});
```

Answer (score 3):

This works with your example, and with most of the containers. I use std::transform, because it can be optimized for each stl iterator. I started out from Baum mit Augen's answer, which was deleted later.

```
template<typename Container, typename Function>
using _mapT = std::vector<typename std::result_of<Function(const typename Container::value_type&)>::type>;

template <typename Container, typename Function>
_mapT<Container, Function> map(const Container &container, Function &&f)
{
    _mapT<Container, Function> ret; ret.reserve(container.size());
    std::transform(container.begin(), container.end(), std::back_inserter(ret), std::forward<Function>(f));
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: That will default construct or value initialize an unknown number of arbitrarily complex types before reassigning them. That is not a good idea. If you really want to use `std::transform` here (which is fine), have a look at `std::back_inserter`).

Comment: @BaummitAugen I ran my version before posting, so this one works with msvc2015. The back_inserter is indeed much better :). I removed C++14 features, this should run with C++11.

Comment: This is almost fine, but `_mapT` is an implementation reserved identifier at global scope, so this is only legal when wrapped in a different scope. I also don't see why you should introduce a new name in the first place, even if you want to go C++11, you can use trailing return types.

Comment: For that you need the `->decltype(..)` and inside you have to type the same (or very similar) long thing. `_mapT` is not reserved because underscore lowercase can be used
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: It cannot be used at the global namespace. *"Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace."* From the link you posted.

Comment: Putting it in some detail namespace is a good practice though.

Comment: Yes, that you can do.

Comment: I'm sorry, but isn't this code wrong? You shouldn't reserve memory if you use back_inserter..

Comment: @user2308211 You are probably confusing `reserve` and `resize`. `reserve` is fine and a good idea if you know the size, `resize` would be wrong.

Comment: @CsabaBálint *"I use std::transform, because it is optimized to each container."* That is not quite true either. First of all, `std::transform` deals with iterators, not containers. Second, `std::transform` is commonly implemented as a loop (see e.g. [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01499_source.html#l04189)), the compiler does the optimizing later. You can not expect a performance gain by switching from loops to `std::transform`. Again, using it here is completely fine, it is just the reason that is wrong.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I know I was vague again. It can be implemented for each container's iterator, and due to its restrictions the compiler can optimize even more.

Comment: Why is this correct? From the documentation: 
"std::transform does not guarantee in-order application".