# Multiplying a a vector of cv::Points2f with a cv::Matx33f

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I have a function that works fine  :

```
cv::Point2f classA::DoStuff(cv::Point2f pTmp){
    cv::Matx33f newMatrix = oldMatrix ; // oldMatrix  is already defined 
    cv::Point3f  newPoint = newMatrix *pTmp;
    cv::Point2f result(newPoint.x, newPoint.y);
    return result;
}
```

well now I want to run this function on a set of points a vector I know I can do this with  a for loop, but from this answer , multiplying a vector with a scalar :

```
std::transform(myv1.begin(), myv1.end(), myv1.begin(),
               std::bind1st(std::multiplies<T>(),3));
```

[Multiply vector elements by a scalar value using STL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885095/c-multiply-vector-elements-by-a-scalar-value-using-stl)

I guess it is possible to do it in one line any idea how to do this  with my function  like :

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> classA::Dostuff(std::vector<cv::Point2f> inputVector){
    cv::Matx33f newMatrix = oldMatrix ; // oldMatrix  is already defined 

..!!!
```

thanks in advance ?

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to run this from inside an instance of `classA`, it would be something like this:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
std::transform(vec.begin(), 
               vec.end(), 
               vec.begin(), 
               std::bind(&classA::DoStuff, this, _1));
```

where `vec` is an `std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>>`. Note you might be making unnecessary and potentially costly copies of the input vector. Unless you need a copy in the function, you may be better off passing a const reference:

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> classA::Dostuff(const std::vector<cv::Point2f>& inputVector);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I got a question what you did is running the DoStuff function for every elements of the inputVector  2. what does the _1 means ?

Comment: @Engine 1) It runs for every element of `vec`. 2. A non-static member function takes an implicit first parameter for `this`, so the vector is actually a second parameter. The `std::bind` binds `this` to the first parameter, and gives you a functor with a single vector parameter.